# Как получить не поддерживающие свойство css с помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-web

Есть ли такой способ, методом *javascript*, который бы мог получить значение из *css*, даже при условиях, когда браузер его не поддерживает. Проблема случилось в том, что вся вертска (практически) была выполнена на единицах измерениях *vh*, *vw* (но при адаптивности под телефоны, где Андроид 4.2 версии, это свойство не узнал.)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование полифиллов.

Ссылка на скачивание https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill
В архиве нам нужен файл "viewport-units-buggyfill.js".
Копируем его к себе в папку с другими js файлами.
Подключаем его в нашем html или php файле и инициализируем следующим кодом:

```
<script>
    window.viewportUnitsBuggyfill.init({
        force: true,
        refreshDebounceWait: 250,
        hacks: window.viewportUnitsBuggyfillHacks
    });
</script>
```

В результате все vw и vh будут пересчитаны в px.

onResize - будет пересчёт.

Проверено.

Тестировал с помощью 1 html файла, его код ниже:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>полифиллы</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            head {
                display: block
            }
            #patched-viewport {
                display: block;
                padding: 10px;
            }
        </style>
        /*установил ширину 90vw*/
        <style media="(max-width: 320px)">
            body { 
                width: 90vw; 
            }
        </style>
        /*установил ширину 70vh*/
        <style media="(min-width: 480px)">
            body { 
                width: 70vh;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Подключил скрипт-->
        <script src="viewport-units-buggyfill.js"></script>

        <!--Инициализировал скрипт-->
        <script>
            window.viewportUnitsBuggyfill.init({
                force: true,
                refreshDebounceWait: 250,
                hacks: window.viewportUnitsBuggyfillHacks
            });
        </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нет стандартного метода, позволяющего сделать такое.

Вам придется получать определения встроенных стилей(вытаскивая `textContent` из `$('style')`'ов) и/или файлов стилей(банальным `$.get()`), после чего производить их парсинг.

Парсер вы можете напистать самостоятельно с нуля, либо использовать готовые библиотеки, например [npm-пакет `css`](https://github.com/reworkcss/css) через [browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы узнать значение (размер шрифта, ширину, высоту и т.д.) обратился к css свойству данного элемента через jQuery

```
var qwe = $('h1').css('fontSize');
```

предварительно установил размер шрифта h1 = 2vh

в результате полученное значение равнялось 18.76px

пример прилагается: http://plnkr.co/edit/OXGknkfNkyo3AeVJz7cR?p=preview

Comment: Это все хорошо, но в этом и проблема, если браузер не поддерживает значение он удаляет его , либо обозначает его как 0px

Comment: Использование полифиллов является решением. ссылка на github https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill . Там есть демо и ссылка на подробное описание. Вот ссылка на примеры, чтобы сразу посмотрели http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths